# Column 'No.' of the table wasn't found. Nav2016 data import to PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, dynamics-nav-2016

I am new to PowerBI and I am trying to get data from Dynamics Nav 2016 in PowerBI Online and I get this error:

```
We couldn't import data from Microsoft Dynamics NAV
Make sure you're entering the information correctly.
Please try again later or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.

Data source type
Processing errorThe column 'No' of the table wasn't found.
Correlation ID28883962-32de-95fe-bf97-85f2c3699964
Activity ID558a71dd-3cee-455e-a8e7-6b00180688f6
Request IDe864480c-e56e-287f-d891-f21a816076ff
Status code500
TimeMon Oct 31 2016 17:09:44 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)
Version13.0.1700.493
Cluster URIhttps://wabi-north-europe-redirect.analysis.windows.net
```

Has anybody encountered something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all oData feeds have data in them.

In my example of this issue, I had to create a Opportunity so that the "SalesOpportunities" feed had at least one entry in it. Otherwise, it caused the error you noted above.

This also means making sure your Account Schedule KPIs has values too.

I wouldn't view the Content Pack as anymore than Demo-esque material. 9 times out of 10 it's not tailored to the organization so the graphs aren't as useful.